# Remove NAs by group

Tags: r, dplyr, na

In R:
I have dataframe test and want dataframe test sum. Basically take the text of the columns and remove the nas by Group

```
test <- data.frame(
   Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
   Text = c("Apple", NA, "Cherry", NA, "Grape"),
    Text2 = c(NA, "Banana", NA, "Cherry", NA)
    )


testsumm<-data.frame(
  Group = c("A","B","C"),
  Text = c("Apple", "Cherry", "Grape"),
 Text2 = c( "Banana",  "Cherry", NA))
```

My real data is big (>5000 row and 30 columns), so I need an automatic solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is each `Group` guaranteed to have only one valid `Text`  and one valid `Text2`?  Your third group has no `Text2` - is that possible in your real dataset?

Comment: yes! For each group, there is only one fruit in each "Text" column. Each group can have one or more fruits. Group C has only one fruit, so Text2 is a NA

Comment: @M-- The linked thread is not quite identical, as this requires considering two variables -  IMO there is enough difference to warrant reopening?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen All the difference that I see is that they need to do `tidyr::fill`. That said, if you cast a reopen vote, I won't make a fuss. ```df1 %>% fill(Text2, .direction = "up") %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(!(is.na(Text) & sum(!is.na(Text)) > 0))```

Comment: In fact, the thread was not quite the same, especially because I am working with strings. But ThomasIsCoding nailed the answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick with `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(. ~ Group, test, na.omit, na.action = na.pass)
  Group   Text  Text2
1     A  Apple Banana
2     B Cherry Cherry
3     C  Grape
```

or, if you want to keep `NA` instead of empty string `""`, you can try

```
aggregate(
    . ~ Group,
    test, 
    \(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, na.omit(x)),
    na.action = na.pass
)
```

which gives

```
  Group   Text  Text2
1     A  Apple Banana
2     B Cherry Cherry
3     C  Grape   <NA>
```

Comment: Excellent, worked smoothly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` to check if all values are NA; if so, keep NA, if not, use `na.omit` to keep the only non-NA. Use `.by` to perform this by group:

```r
library(dplyr)
test |> 
  summarise(across(contains("Text"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, na.omit(.x))), 
            .by = Group)

#   Group   Text  Text2
# 1     A  Apple Banana
# 2     B Cherry Cherry
# 3     C  Grape   <NA>
```

Comment: I got an error message: Error in `across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: It's probably because you have not updated `dplyr`, `.by` is quite recent

Comment: indeed! I updated it and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would `summarise` to `sort` with na.last = TRUE, then `filter` out the rows with all NAs.

```
library(dplyr)

test |> 
    group_by(Group) |> 
    summarise(across(matches("Text\\d*"),
                     \(x) sort(x, na.last = TRUE))) |> 
    filter(!if_all(matches("Text\\d*"), is.na)) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Group Text   Text2 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 A     Apple  Banana
2 B     Cherry Cherry
3 C     Grape  NA
```

Comment: this gave me the following error: Error in `across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
  Text = c("Apple", NA, "Cherry", NA, "Grape"),
  Text2 = c(NA, "Banana", NA, "Cherry", NA)
)
test |> group_by(Group) |> mutate(Text = na.omit(unique(Text)),
                                  Text2 = ifelse(length(na.omit(unique(Text2))) > 0,
                                                 na.omit(unique(Text2)), 
                                                 NA_character_)) |>
  distinct()
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group Text   Text2 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 A     Apple  Banana
2 B     Cherry Cherry
3 C     Grape  NA
```

This works by using `na.omit(unique(...))` - list all the unique values and drop the NAs.
Since we want to retain an NA in Text2 if there are no valid fruits, we add a test and if `na.omit(unique(...))` doesn't retain any values, put in NA.
Grouping the data frame first just makes sure we are only looking for unique values within each Group.
`distinct()` drops unneeded rows.

Comment: thanks! But I got an error message Error in `[[<-`:
! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 5 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 3 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 3 to size 5.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.